# A matrix has a cyclic vector iff every eigenvector is of geometric multilplicity 1

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

In a finite dimensional space, prove that a matrix has a cyclic vector iff every eigenvalue is of geometric multilplicity 1.

I can show that if a matrix has a cyclic vector, then every eigenvalue is of geometric multiplicity 1, but I don't know how to show the other direction. If all eigenvalues are distinct, then I know how to prove the matrix has a cyclic vector, but if not all eigenvalues are distinct, then no idea.

Second question: does the above statement imply that the set of cyclic matrices is open?

(If a matrix has a cyclic vector, then it is called cyclic matrix.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If two eigenvalues are equal / not distinct, wouldn't that make the corresponding geometric multiplicity higher than $1$?

Comment: dou you mean geometric multiplicity of *eigenvalues* ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right, I mean geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues

Comment: If two eigenvalues are equal, that only make the corresponding algebraic multiplicity higher than 1, the corresponding geometric multiplicity is not necessarily higher than 1

Comment: Maybe think about a $2 \times 2$ matrix in Jordan form with equal eigenvalues.  Once you understand that case, go on to the general case.

Comment: I note that Yung doesn't say what scalars to use.  Does that mean a general field?  Or does that mean real/complex as the default case?

Comment: The scalars are complex numbers